# How to replace a part of a string maintaining the other one intact in IntelliJ or VSCode?

Tags: regex, dart, visual-studio-code, regex-replace

I'm developing a Flutter app.

I have used a function written by me to calculate the sizes of every stuff. This was called `scaleAdapter` and its signature was this one:

`scaleAdapter(aNumber)`

This is used everywhere in the project.
I recently however discovered that this approach is not useful in many cases and I want to migrate to the [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) package which is very good. The fact is that now in every file I should substitute

`scaleAdapter(aNumber)` with `aNumber.aUnit` 
where `aUnit` is:

- w for horizontal
- h for vertical values
- sp for size values
- r for round values (such as border-radius)

in a concrete example

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: scaleAdapter(22),
  height: scaleAdapter(22),
  child: SvgPicture.asset(
    'assets/images/svg/yellow/prezzo.svg',
  ),
),
```

Now it must become:

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 22.w,
  height: 22.h,
  child: SvgPicture.asset(
    'assets/images/svg/yellow/prezzo.svg',
  ),
),
```

Since it is insane to think about manually substituting everything I was wondering if there is some function in IntelliJ or also VSCode that can do the work for me.

I am able with IntelliJ to search for a specific pattern using a RegEx, (for example by searching `width: scaleAdapter\(.\)` I find all the width values with the old function) but I don't know how to keep the original value when substituting.

Any help please?

Comment: You can easily combine this into one find/replace , see https://regex101.com/r/pOb1J5/1.  Works in one file or across multiple files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VSC

regex search for: `width: scaleAdapter\(([^)]+)\)`

replace with: `width: $1.w`

similar for the other cases of `h`, `sp` and `r`

Comment: I ended up asking also to chatGPT and I was going to autopost an answer, but you were quicker :D so accepted!!

Comment: @AleTheFe ChatGPT answers are not allowed here

Comment: in fact, better yours ^^